# How to combine 2 select statements with inner joins and result them in different columns

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT CONCAT(users.user_fname,' ',users.user_lname) AS lawyer,casemaster.case_title,casemaster.plaintiff,casemaster.defendant,casemaster.recordingdate,casemaster.hearingdate,casemaster.status 
FROM users  
INNER JOIN casemaster ON users.id = casemaster.lawyer
```

AND

```
SELECT CONCAT(users.user_fname,' ',users.user_lname) AS judge,casemaster.case_title,casemaster.plaintiff,casemaster.defendant,casemaster.recordingdate,casemaster.hearingdate,casemaster.status 
FROM users  
INNER JOIN casemaster ON users.id = casemaster.judge
```

results:

```
col1 :lawyer and col2:judge
john Doe         jane doe
```

Comment: There's no question here, just two queries.

Comment: two queries that I want to run as one statement and get results in two separate results instead of 1 result

Comment: The details of what you want and what you've tried so far should be in the question, not comments.